# Process.Start on gpg.exe just hangs

Tags: c#, gnupg

I'm trying to run gpg.exe from C# using ProcessStartInfo()/Process.Start(). When I run it from cmd it works. I copy and paste the exact command I ran from cmd into my C# app and gpg.exe opens but it just hangs. Doesn't show any text in the window and just sits there doing nothing. What could be going on?

```
var gpg = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\GnuPG\gpg.exe", @"--batch --yes --output c:\applications\development\invoicedecryption\temp\invoice.csv --passphrase-fd <C:\GNUPG\pasfraz.txt --decrypt C:\applications\development\invoicedecryption\temp\Invoices.csv.pgp");

var prs = new Process();
prs.StartInfo = gpg;
prs.Start();
```

Comment: Probably the process waits for you to read its output

Comment: What does the first character of `<C:\GNUPG\pasfraz.txt` do? How might that relate to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: @dlxeon 1. How would I do that? 2. The file doesn't get decrypted so if this is the case then it's blocking the decryption from happening.

Comment: @mjwills That's a good question. I believe it's reading what's in the file and inserting that text into the command. It works when I type that in cmd.exe is all I know.

Comment: Did you read the link I suggested?